# Inherit from CSS ID

Tags: css

Copied an Arduino example from https://github.com/m1cr0lab-esp32/remote-control-with-websocket. This is using a single LED for websockets, but I need multiple. The backend stuff works fine.

```css
#led {
  position: relative;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2.5em;
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 50% 20%, #b30000 0%, #330000 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em rgba(102, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#led.on {
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 50% 75%, red 0%, #990000 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 1em 1.5em rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#led:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .3em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 60%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div id="led" class="%button1%"></div>
  <button id="toggle1">Snowman</button>
</div>
```

I have a total of 5 LED's. Currently I simply copied the CSS stuff 5 times, but there has to be a better way.

Can anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: Use class instead of id (#led becomes .led) and use it in as many elements as you like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

Comment: So I changed #led to .led and then added #led1 .led {position: relative;}. I need to enter something in the curly brackets for some reason.  Also the led doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Change your id `led` to a class and duplicate to match the number of lights you need (i did 5 for the example).

In addition, to be able to target every led by itself via JS or CSS i would add a **unique** id to every led.

By adding the class `on` to an element you can turn the light on (see the light for the grinch in the example).

```css
.led {
  position: relative;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2.5em;
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 50% 20%, #b30000 0%, #330000 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em rgba(102, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.led.on {
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 50% 75%, red 0%, #990000 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 1em 1.5em rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.led:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .3em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 60%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div id="led1" class="led" class="%button1%"></div>
  <button id="toggle1">Snowman</button>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div id="led2" class="led" class="%button1%"></div>
  <button id="toggle2">Pumpkin</button>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div id="led3" class="led on" class="%button1%"></div>
  <button id="toggle3">Grinch</button>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div id="led4" class="led" class="%button1%"></div>
  <button id="toggle4">Santa on the Roof</button>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div id="led5" class="led" class="%button1%"></div>
  <button id="toggle5">Reindeers</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian! For some reason the double class didn't work, but you pointed out where to look and I was able to solve it.
Very much appreciated! Vielen dank!